# Retrofit exceptions handling

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, okhttp

I need to handle different exceptions with Retrofit when it called `onFailure` method and depends on exception display some error message.

Now, I'm displaying only toast with a message `Error`. I think that this is not enough.

What is the appropriate way to notify the user about the problems in the REST call ?

Comment: Do you want to give different messages to the user according to the reason of failure?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp, yep. But I don't know which exceptions should I handle :(

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options to notify the user about the errors that happen in the application functionality. When it comes to network calls, one sensible way is to prompt a user with an appropriate message, based on the http code of the response (400, 404 ,403 or 200) and enabling her to retry that.

The **SnackBar** is one of the Material design components that is available in Android, enabling the developer to show a message on any part of the screen (top, bottom , ...) and integrating some function into it, so that the user can "retry" or "undo" what she has done.

[image]

It is very simple and straightforward to implement :

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
    .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           //your retry functionality
        }
    });
```

I recommend you to use snackbar for showing the message to the user with a custom functionality.

For showing the proper message based on the http response from the api you are using, you should know the [meaning of each Http status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html).

For a good tutorial on implementing and customizing Snackbars, you can study this tutorial on [Android SnackBar Example by AndroidHive.](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not inform the user about anything technical, they will probably not understand it (e.g. "ERROR 5653"). So the way you handle failures depends on the context of the requests. If the request kills the whole flow of the application you might want to do more then only display a toast, but if it doesn't I usually show a `Toast`/`Snackbar` with a generic error message like: "Something went wrong".